# yii2: new action is notFound 404

Tags: model-view-controller, yii, yii2

i want add a new action in my controller  in yii2 project :

i have error for add any new action !
new action have this error : `Not Found (#404)`

```
<?php

namespace soft\controllers;

use Yii;
use soft\models\Reserve;
use soft\models\ReserveSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use \yii\web\Response;
use yii\helpers\Html;

/**
 * ReserveController implements the CRUD actions for Reserve model.
 */
class ReserveController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors() {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['post'],
                    'bulk-delete' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Reserve models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex() {
        $searchModel = new ReserveSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
                    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    public function actionJson() {
        die;
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Reserve model.
     * @param string $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id) {
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        if ($request->isAjax) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return [
                'title' => "Reserve #" . $id,
                'content' => $this->renderAjax('view', [
                    'model' => $this->findModel($id),
                ]),
                'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) .
                Html::a('Edit', ['update', 'id' => $id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'role' => 'modal-remote'])
            ];
        } else {
            return $this->render('view', [
                        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Reserve model.
     * For ajax request will return json object
     * and for non-ajax request if creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate() {
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        $model = new Reserve();

        if ($request->isAjax) {
            /*
             *   Process for ajax request
             */
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            if ($request->isGet) {
                return [
                    'title' => "Create new Reserve",
                    'content' => $this->renderAjax('create', [
                        'model' => $model,
                    ]),
                    'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) .
                    Html::button('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'type' => "submit"])
                ];
            } else if ($model->load($request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                return [
                    'forceReload' => '#crud-datatable-pjax',
                    'title' => "Create new Reserve",
                    'content' => '<span class="text-success">Create Reserve success</span>',
                    'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) .
                    Html::a('Create More', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'role' => 'modal-remote'])
                ];
            } else {
                return [
                    'title' => "Create new Reserve",
                    'content' => $this->renderAjax('create', [
                        'model' => $model,
                    ]),
                    'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) .
                    Html::button('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'type' => "submit"])
                ];
            }
        } else {
            /*
             *   Process for non-ajax request
             */
            if ($model->load($request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('create', [
                            'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Reserve model.
     * For ajax request will return json object
     * and for non-ajax request if update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param string $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id) {
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($request->isAjax) {
            /*
             *   Process for ajax request
             */
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            if ($request->isGet) {
                return [
                    'title' => "Update Reserve #" . $id,
                    'content' => $this->renderAjax('update', [
                        'model' => $model,
                    ]),
                    'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) .
                    Html::button('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'type' => "submit"])
                ];
            } else if ($model->load($request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                return [
                    'forceReload' => '#crud-datatable-pjax',
                    'title' => "Reserve #" . $id,
                    'content' => $this->renderAjax('view', [
                        'model' => $model,
                    ]),
                    'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) .
                    Html::a('Edit', ['update', 'id' => $id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'role' => 'modal-remote'])
                ];
            } else {
                return [
                    'title' => "Update Reserve #" . $id,
                    'content' => $this->renderAjax('update', [
                        'model' => $model,
                    ]),
                    'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) .
                    Html::button('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'type' => "submit"])
                ];
            }
        } else {
            /*
             *   Process for non-ajax request
             */
            if ($model->load($request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('update', [
                            'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete an existing Reserve model.
     * For ajax request will return json object
     * and for non-ajax request if deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param string $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id) {
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        if ($request->isAjax) {
            /*
             *   Process for ajax request
             */
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ['forceClose' => true, 'forceReload' => '#crud-datatable-pjax'];
        } else {
            /*
             *   Process for non-ajax request
             */
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete multiple existing Reserve model.
     * For ajax request will return json object
     * and for non-ajax request if deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param string $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionBulkDelete() {
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        $pks = explode(',', $request->post('pks')); // Array or selected records primary keys
        foreach ($pks as $pk) {
            $model = $this->findModel($pk);
            $model->delete();
        }

        if ($request->isAjax) {
            /*
             *   Process for ajax request
             */
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ['forceClose' => true, 'forceReload' => '#crud-datatable-pjax'];
        } else {
            /*
             *   Process for non-ajax request
             */
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Reserve model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param string $id
     * @return Reserve the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id) {
        if (($model = Reserve::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }

}
```

why action `json` is 
not found but action `create` is Available ؟!

this is working :`admin2.localhost/en/reserve/create`
 but this is not working : `admin2.localhost/en/reserve/json`

this is my main.php :

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require (__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require (__DIR__ . '/params.php')
);

$config = [
    'id' => 'app-soft',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'soft\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [],
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'main\models\custom\SoftUser',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
        ],
        'runtime'=>[
            'class'=>'soft\config\Runtime',
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'rules' => [
                'package' => 'site/package',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

return $config;
```

Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Looks like actionJson() is define outside of class.

Comment: this mistake is only in my post!

Comment: Still mistake in your code. Now actionjson method in actioncreate().

Can you  please provide proper code?

Comment: i added all of my controller in this post!!

Comment: Are u using any other URL manager?

Answer (score 0):

my params.php have problem  and fixed :

```
 'urlRules' => [
        '' => 'site/index',
        'login/' => 'site/login',
        'signup/' => 'site/signup',
        '<controller:[\w-]+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:[\w-]+>/create' => '<controller>/create',
        '<controller:[\w-]+>/update/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/update',
        '<controller:[\w-]+>/delete/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/delete',
        '<controller:[\w-]+>/bulk-delete' => '<controller>/bulk-delete',
    ]
```

Comment: What's the reason of that?

Comment: This line not was in my code :

   '<controller:[\w-]+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',